# What does the FIWARE acronym IDAS stand for?

Tags: fiware

OK - this is minor but has been bugging me - I can't find a definition of the IDAS acronym anywhere. Does anyone know what IDAS stand for (from a FIWARE context)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IDAS stands for Intelligent Data Advances Solution. It was the name of the platform that implemented the FIWARE Backend Device Management GE component.

Answer (score 2):

Its a legacy term. It comes from a product developed at Telefonica ten years ago (it was called SBC later on). I can’t remember what the acronym stands for :) but it seems to still alive at some fiware fora, maybe for some administrative purposes.

Nowadays I think it is the name received by the acquisition layer services/community.

For practical purposes IoTAgents completely substitute the IDAS as technology and as terminology.